# Confused about App Dev process- Only trying to link to a website

Tags: facebook, development-environment

I am trying to get Facebook features (like button, and login capabilities) on my website but I am having a tough time figuring out how to do it.  I have a Facebook page for my website too, I do not have an app, but from what I've seen I'm supposed to create this App profile through Facebook in order to access all of these features.  I am simply confused.  I have a website, I have a Facebook page for that website, now I want to link the two.  Again, I do not have an app for the site, yet, as it is in its early development stages.  Please help me figure out what I must do to link my website to Facebook capabilities

Comment: You don't need to have an FB app for those features. Have you checked out the social plugin's page? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

Comment: Yeah- but to install the javascript sdk onto my html file don't I need to enter the app id and all that?

Comment: and for that javascript sdk to work do I need to enter anything in the head section or is that whole process done in the body? (sorry relatively new at this)

Comment: Facebook's documentation is pretty bad. The Appid parameter, from what I can recall, is not actually required. I usually just throw the JS and HTML all in the body, but there are probably better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out their site? https://developers.facebook.com/
All you need to do after registering with Facebook as a developer, you should have a control panel. After that you should have a dev key, so when you make an API call to Facebook that you can authentic yourself as a registered developer. You do need to enter the javascript file in the head section so that when you call the Facebook API your Javascript code knows to reference the calls.

Answer (score 0):

Just "create an application" for the website. I think what you are most confused about is actually *building* an app.

"Create an application" provides a reference for your application to reside. All Facebook plugins currently must be processed through the JS SDK which needs an application (reference) to make requests. You will see the benefits of doing this when using facebook.com/insights

Also your Facebook fan page has nothing to do with your website, think of it separately, it will cause less confusion. There is no way to *link* them.

**Summary**: Just click the "Create app" button, set the domain to your website domain and supply the application id to the JS SDK.